# How do I get a log file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a file full of logs! I called them apache.logs.
So now I need to get them in Laravel and I don't know how.
I just want to save all logs in a variable (`$logs`) and view them.

```
public function getlogs ()
    {
        $logs = \Request::file('apache.log');
        return view('logs' , [
            'all_logs' => $logs
        ]);
    }
```

This doesn't work and I don't know what I need to change.

Comment: Can I ask which Laravel version, you're using?

Comment: where is the `apache.log` in laravel?

Comment: in my project folder - just like the composer.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using `\Request::file` then the file should come along with the request params, But here seems like you want to access a stored file in file system using laravel

to do that

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
$logs = \File::get('apache.log');
return view('logs' , [
    'all_logs' => $logs
]);
```

**UPDATE**

if you file is in root same like `composer.json` then you need to change the path to match with it like

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
$path = base_path()."/apache.log"; //get the apache.log file in root
$logs = \File::get($path);

return view('logs' , [
    'all_logs' => $logs
]);
```

wrap this in a `try catch` block for best practice, because in some case if `apache.log` not exists or not accessible laravel trow a exception, we need to handle it

```
try {

    ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
    $path = base_path()."/apache.log"; //get the apache.log file in root
    $logs = \File::get($path);

    return view('logs' , [
        'all_logs' => $logs
    ]);

} catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $exception) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

Comment: thanks this works-- now i have a other porblem haha but i dont think anyone could help me there xD

Comment: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 176646626 bytes) - haha :D

Comment: lol yeah seems like a large file put this and check  `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');`, made a update please check :)